# Problema inicialização Tomcat 9 - #algaworks

Tags: java, tomcat

Seguindo o livro da #algaworks, tentei instalar e verificar a funcionalidade do Tomcat (tanto a versão 8 quanto a versão 9), e ao abrir o arquivo startup.bat e acessar via navegador o localhost:8080, nada acontece. Tentei abrir via prompt de comando e a mensagem retornada foi a seguinte:

> neither the java_home nor the jre_home environment variable is defined
>   at least one of these environment variable is needed to run this
>   program

Como sou iniciante, não estou conseguindo compreendê-la nem resolvê-la. Alguém passou por isso?

Comment: Pessoal, resolvi este problema da seguinte forma: eu estava baixando a versão 64 bits do Tomcat 9 e descompactando na pasta C. Provável que desta forma eu estava deixando de lado alguma configuração necessária. Pesquisando, descobri que tem uma versão que parte de um instalador (que é a última citada no download do tomkat: "32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer (pgp, md5, sha1)"). Dessa forma, ao instalar a partir deste .exe e acessar o localhost:8080, tudo funcionou corretamente.

Answer (score 3):

Se desejar instalar e configurar a versão zipada, pode-se seguir os seguintes passos:

**Pré-Requisitos:** Tenha o JDK instalado. (irei supor que o jdk está instalado no diretório *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45*)

**Passo 1:** Faça o download (da versão desejada) do tomcat no site oficial http://tomcat.apache.org/, preferencialmente o .zip do tópico "*Binary Distributions*" e extraia no diretório desejado (Irei supor que extraiu no diretório *C:\* e renomeou a pasta para *tomcat*). Sendo assim, o tomcat está instalado em *C:\tomcat*.

**Passo 2:** Crie as variáveis de ambiente necessárias para que o prompt de comando do windows reconheça o tomcat e o jdk nos seguintes passos:

> **2.1:** Abra o "Painel de Controle" > Busque e abra a opção "Sistema" > Na lateral esquerda da janela clique na opção "Configurações Avançadas do Sistema" > Na aba "Avançado" da nova janela clique na opção "Variáveis de Ambiente".
>
> **2.2:** Na janela que abriu, na área "Variáveis de Sistema" clique em "Novo".
>
> **2.3:** Na nova janela que abriu terá o campo "Nome da Variável" e "Valor da Variável". No primeiro coloque CATALINA_HOME e no segundo campo coloque o caminho da pasta onde extraiu o tomcat (neste nosso exemplo foi *C:\tomcat*). Finalize clicando em OK.
>
> **2.4:** Execute novamente os passo **2.2** e **2.3**. Executando novamente o passo **2.3**, insira desta vez no primeira campo o valor JAVA_HOME e no segundo campo coloque o caminho do seu jdk (neste exemplo está em C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45). Finalize clicando em OK.
>
> **2.5:** Busque nessa mesma janela na área "Variáveis de Ambiente" a variável **Path**, selecione-a e clique em *Editar*.
>
> **2.6:** Na nova janela que abriu e no campo "Valor da Variável" vá para o final do texto que já tem lá e adicione um ponto-e-vírgula (;) após todo o texto.
>
> **2.7:** Adicione o seguinte texto após o ponto-e-vírgula que você colocou: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin
>
> **2.8:** Finalize clicando em OK em todas as janelas abertas neste passo **2**.
>
> **2.9:** Abra um NOVO prompt de comando e execute o comando "java" (sem as aspas) e depois o comando "catalina" (sem as aspas). Se você não recebeu a mensagem "*...is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*" significa que você adicionou as variáveis de ambiente corretamente.

**Passo 3:** Adicione suas aplicações na pasta *webapps*.

**Passo 4:** No prompt de comando digite "catalina run" (sem as aspas) para iniciar o servidor tomcat. Se a configuração foi feita corretamente o servidor estará acessível em localhost:8080. E para acessar uma página que esteja na pasta webapps/teste, por exemplo teste.html, acesse localhost:8080/teste/teste.html

Comment: Excelente resposta! Funcionou. Obrigado.